# Javascript: Get mouse position relative to parent element

Tags: javascript, mouse-position

Is there any way to get mouse position relative to it's parent element?

Let's say I have a structure:

```
<div id="parent">
    <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

When I bring my mouse over `span` element I need to get its position relative to its parent element (`<div id="parent">`). PageX/ClientX give me position relative to page/client area, so it's not working for me.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Subtract the viewport-relative position of the parent element you can get via `getBoundingClientRect()` from the mouse position in the event's `clientX` and `clientY` to get relative position.

For example:

```
element.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    let bounds = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
    let x = e.clientX - bounds.left;
    let y = e.clientY - bounds.top;

    console.log(x, y);
});
```

Where `element` is your inner element receiving the event, and `parent` is your desired reference for the coordinates.

Comment: this doesn't work if some descendant element uses relative or absolute positioning.

Comment: @Robert Seems that somebody added code to my answer without actually reading the answer and added incorrect code. I've updated it now with a better method.

Comment: You're a beast, thank you!

Comment: This! Lifesaver!

Answer (score 6):

**jquery offset()** method handles parent positioning, so

```
function onsomemouseevent(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left;
}
```

is plain browser abstracted jquery.

Comment: May be also useful to use e.currentTarget, when you are working with element with child elements

Answer (score 2):

Here is a React specific example, but I assume the concepts would work even outside React.

```
onMouseMove={(e) => {
   var x = e.clientX - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
   var y = e.clientY - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;

   // Do something with x and y
}}
```

Also, I found that throttling the mouse move capturing is useful when you're doing a lot of computation. Here's a nice [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23181284/4933858) that showed how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`offsetParent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent) property.

Try this:

```
positionX = document.getElementById('childId').offsetParent.offsetLeft;
positionY = document.getElementById('childId').offsetParent.offsetLeft;
```