# Is there a way to re-purpose an SVG file?

Tags: html, svg

I was wondering is there a way to re-purpose an SVG file?

What I mean is, I have my logo SVG file in my header area, the whole thing is set to black, will I be able to use the exact same file in my footer area with different colors? Or do I have to create another SVG file for that?

Comment: Specify the "html" tag if it is relevant.

Comment: One way to do this is to serve it through your server's scripting language, and add a query string to modify certain properties (e.g. colour) of the logo. That would save you having to maintain several similar copies of the file.

Comment: Ading to @halfer's idea, you make your SVG with its colors being unique text (e.g. `%myLogoColor%`), then use server side scripting to replace `$myLogoColor$` with anything you might want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your SVG embedded in an SVG tag (not in an `img` tag) your html would look somewhat like:

```
<header>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <path d="..." class="logo_fill">
  </svg>
<header>

<footer>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <path d="..." class="logo_fill">
  </svg>
<footer>
```

Then, in your CSS you can state:

```
header svg .logo_fill {
    fill: red;
}

footer svg .logo_fill {
    fill: gray;
}
```

Comment: This might work, but my logo contains lots of different elements, not just paths, it has paths, circles, lines, etc. does that mean i have to add the class tag to each element I have?

Comment: Also my svg file is external and I am calling it with <object> tag, is it better to make it in-line?

Comment: I would not make it inline if I had the choice. The object tag might be fine, depending on your specific scenario. See this thread for a link to the W3C SVG Primer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files This tutorial also discuss a few options. http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/Using_SVG_with_HTML5_tutorial

Answer (score 1):

SVG is XML so it's repurposable "by design". As @halfer and @Kroltan already pointed out, you can use server side languages to change the logo color.

In case you don't have access to the server side , you could also use client side Scripting or even XSLT to do this.

See this thread as a starter... [Changing SVG image color with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872947/changing-svg-image-color-with-javascript)