# How to hide an element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[image: this is the graph and i need to hide the dates]

how can i hide the date on the graph

```
<div class="highcharts-container" id="highcharts-6">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1330"   height="532"><desc>Created with Highstock 1.3.7</desc><defs><clipPath id="highcharts-7"><rect fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="1239" height="290"></rect></clipPath></defs>
<path fill="none" d="M 71 45 L 71 335 180 335 180 45" zIndex="5"></path>
<text x="126" y="29" transform="translate(0,0)" visibility="visible">
<tspan x="126">7/9/15</tspan></text></svg></div>
```

Comment: won't be much different than this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872947/changing-svg-image-color-with-javascript

Comment: i tried a lot of options but nothing is working, please help

Comment: "I tried a lot of options". How about you showing us what you tried?

Comment: `$('tspan').remove()` to remove it completely and to empty the `tspan` just use `$('tspan').html('')`

Comment: Why you cannot set a null value for point ? Then point will be empty ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's just one, then this code should work:

```
document.querySelector("tspan").style.display = "none";
```

If there are multiple then:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("tspan"), function(item) {
  item.style.display = "none";
});
```

Or if you want to use jQuery:

```
$("tspan").hide();
```

Comment: there are multiple tspans. I did not copy the entire code

Comment: I tried this which did not work $('div.highcharts-container > svg > text').find('tspan').html("");

Comment: Dave, so can I do this

Comment: $('div.highcharts-container > svg > text').forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("tspan"), function(item) {
  item.style.display = "none";
});

Comment: If you're using jQuery, just use the last line in my answer--don't overcomplicate it.