# Changing css fill for svg with JS

Tags: javascript, css, svg, fill

I'm trying to change svg fill color, which is defined with css, using JS. For some reason it doesn't work. Here is my code:

SVG itself (in short):

```
<svg id="secondalert"><style>.cls-1{fill:#000000;}</style></svg>
```

And JS to target and change it:

```
function() {
    var svg_css = document.getElementsByClassName('.cls-1');

    if (random_value < 20) {
        svg_css.css({
            "fill": "#EF4136"
        });

    } else {
        svg_css.css({
            "fill": "#EF4136"
        });
    }
}
```

Something is not coming together, a fill color stays black as it is in style tag.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you calling your function?, also over-riding inline styles generally requires an !important after the property.

Comment: Its jquery syntax, not pure javascript. Try `svg_css.style.fill = "#EF4136"`

Comment: Possibly duplicate from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872947/changing-svg-image-color-with-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing SVG image color with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872947/changing-svg-image-color-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `svg_css.css({"fill" : "#hexadecimal"})` you can use `svg_css.style.fill = "#hexadecimal"`

And also, when you use `getElementsByClassName` it returns an array, instead use `getElementById` or choose the element inside array:

```
svg_css = document.getElementsByClassName('.cls-1')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Before we get to changing the style, there are a few things to watch out for:

```
var svg_css = document.getElementsByClassName('.cls-1');
```

Getting elements by class name is fine, but the `.` selector is specific to CSS. This means that `svg_css` will be set to any elements with the class of `.cls-1` NOT `cls-1`.

Secondly, There are no elements with the class of `cls-1` in your HTML.  An element with such class would look like:

```
<svg id="secondalert" class="cls-1"></svg>
```

I'm guessing `random_value` is declared somewhere else, but you probably want a random value within that function.

What you need to do is get the elements by class name, then since that returns a list of elements, select which one you want (in our case the first one.) Then, to set the fill, use the `style` property which has a `fill` property.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('cls-1');
elements[0].style.fill = Math.random()*40 > 20 ? "blue" : "red";
```

```html
<svg class="cls-1" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1417 1632h-1118v-480h-160v640h1438v-640h-160v480zm-942-524l33-157 783 165-33 156zm103-374l67-146 725 339-67 145zm201-356l102-123 614 513-102 123zm397-378l477 641-128 96-477-641zm-718 1471v-159h800v159h-800z"/></svg>
```