# Interacting with SVG file to change color on tap

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, interactive, flutter-image

I have an SVG file, how can i interact with it and change color of different portions of SVG file.

I am trying this thing very first time, and i am confused how to achieve it. Any possible and step by step solutions?
TIA

Comment: please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872947/changing-svg-image-color-with-javascript

Comment: This is something to change color of whole SVG. I want to change the color of different portions of SVG file @enxaneta

Comment: To answer the question we need to know how you are going to use the SVG. Please include some of your code in the question so that we can help you.