# Mouse coordinates restricted to 1 element and not the page size

Tags: javascript, events, canvas, mouse, coordinates

Hi, guys i am working on a way to draw with your mouse with Canvas.
This is how far i am:

```
function drawdraw(){
    test = document.getElementById('test');
    ctx = test.getContext('2d');

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", drawing,false);
}

function drawing(e){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,200);
    var xPos = e.pageX-test.offsetLeft;
    var yPos = e.pageY-test.offsetTop;
    ctx.fillRect(xPos, yPos,30,30);
}
window.addEventListener("load", drawdraw,false);
```

My current problem is that I do not have the right cursor coordinates.
I tried e.clientX , e.clientX and the example above.

I want to be able to move my canvas dynamicly, and I want the coordinates of the mouse to be 0,0 at top left of the canvas, and 500,200 at the bottom right of the canvas. In other words I just want my coordinates to be within the canvas, and not coordinates of the page.
Anyone? :)

Btw. I am interested in a javascript solution, so if I can, I want to avoid jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test` is a local variable of function `drawdraw` and you are using it also in `drawing` function. You need to declare it as global variable.

Comment: thats true, i fixed that, but still no result

Comment: my current result is that it registres my mouse events at about 200px from the top, and 0px from the left. this is relative to the body tag or html tag if you will.
But i need it to be relative to the canvas, i just do not know the code

Comment: @KristianDaugaard `e.pageX` / `e.pageY` gives you values of cursor position from html document. You can subtract canvas `top` / `left` position from `e.pageX` / `e.pageY` and it will give you relative to canvas.

Comment: @Aspring Aqib i am aware, then what i am asking, instead of e.page / e.client
What gives you the values of cursor position from another object? does such thing not exist?

Comment: Ahh, IDTS! but i give a try on it ;)

Comment: It happens so that my canvas element is inside a wrapper that has a margin of auto, for resolution compability.

That is why i asked so specific as i did, in regards to getting the coordinates of only the canvas. so topleft canvas = 0,0 and bottomright = 500,200

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614461/javascipt-get-mouse-position-relative-to-parent-element .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24625/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-kristian-daugaard)