# Can you ease integers using jquery for animating svg filter specular lighting?

Tags: jquery, svg

I'm using `feSpecularLighting` svg filter and I am animating the `fePointLight` position where the mousemoves on desktop.

```
<feSpecularLighting in="blur" surfaceScale="15" specularConstant="2.5" specularExponent="200" result="specOut" lighting-color="white">
    <fePointLight x="-10000" y="-10000" z="8000" />
</feSpecularLighting>
```

I cant seem to find a way to use CSS transition effects to ease `x` and `y` attribute changes, I don't think svg filters work like this. So I'm wondering is it possible to ease the integer changes for `x` and `y`?

See working example below, with **no easing** of `x` and `y` attribute values.

```js
// lighting effect variables
let lightDist = 10000;
let currentLightPos = {
  x: -lightDist,
  y: -lightDist
};
let currentMousePos = {
  x: -1,
  y: -1
};
let windowWidth = $(window).outerWidth();
let windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
let ratio = {
  x: lightDist / (windowWidth / 2),
  y: lightDist / (windowHeight / 2)
};

// when the window is resized
$(window).on('resize', function() {

  // update lighting effect variables
  windowWidth = $(window).outerWidth();
  windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
  ratio = {
    x: lightDist / (windowWidth / 2),
    y: lightDist / (windowHeight / 2)
  };

});

// when the mouse is moved (desktop)
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {

  // get our current mouse position
  currentMousePos.x = e.pageX;
  currentMousePos.y = e.pageY;

  // if mouse is on right side of window
  if (currentMousePos.x > (windowWidth / 2)) {

    // calculate the positive light x position
    currentLightPos.x = ratio.x * (currentMousePos.x - (windowWidth / 2));

    // if mouse is on left side of window
  } else if (currentMousePos.x < (windowWidth / 2)) {

    // calculate the negative light x position
    currentLightPos.x = -lightDist + (ratio.x * currentMousePos.x);

  }

  // calculate the negative light y position
  // if mouse is on bottom side of window
  if (currentMousePos.y > (windowHeight / 2)) {

    // calculate the positive light y position
    currentLightPos.y = ratio.y * (currentMousePos.y - (windowHeight / 2));

    // if mouse is on top side of window
  } else if (currentMousePos.y < (windowHeight / 2)) {

    // calculate the negative light y position
    currentLightPos.y = -lightDist + (ratio.y * currentMousePos.y);

  }
  
  // console.log(currentLightPos.x, currentLightPos.y);

  // update shine filter fePointLight attributes
  $('fePointLight').attr({
    'x': currentLightPos.x,
    'y': currentLightPos.y
  });

});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<svg class="circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" filter="url(#shine)" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="shine" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="150%" height="150%">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4" result="blur" />
        <feSpecularLighting in="blur" surfaceScale="15" specularConstant="2.5" specularExponent="200" result="specOut" lighting-color="white">
            <fePointLight x="-10000" y="-10000" z="8000" />
        </feSpecularLighting>
        <feComposite in="specOut" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="specOut2" />
        <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut2" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" />
    </filter>
</svg>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To emulate the issue I'm having, if you move your mouse outside of the example window, and bring your mouse back into the window in a different position, you will notice the point lighting instantly jumps to the newly calculated position.

I'm wondering is it possible to ease this, so the `x` and `y` integers always ease in to their newly calculated position, rather than instantly jumping to new position if you bring your mouse into the window from a different side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Aside: while your question says "integers", the `<fePointLight>` attributes take real numbers also. So that is no detriment to fluent easing.)

You can do this with a declarative SMIL animation in two steps: first, you declare two [`<animate>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#AnimateElement) elements for the two `x` and `y` attributes of `<fePointLight>`. `restart="always"` makes sure this animation can restart at any time, even if the animation is currently running. `fill="freeze"` preserves the value after the end of the animation.

But the main trick is to set `begin="indefinite"`. This postpones the start of the animation until it is triggered from a Javascript API call.

```
<fePointLight x="-10000" y="-10000" z="8000">
    <animate id="anim_x" attributeName="x"
             begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" restart="always"
             from="-10000" to="-10000" fill="freeze" />
    <animate id="anim_y" attributeName="y"
             begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" restart="always"
             from="-10000" to="-10000" fill="freeze" />
</fePointLight>
```

I've left the easing function at its default `linear` value. For more complex behavior, the syntax is a bit more involved than CSS easing functions. Something comparable to `ease-in-out` would look like this:

```
    <animate id="anim_x" attributeName="x"
             begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" restart="always"
             calcMode="spline" values="-10000;-10000" keyTimes="0;1"
             keySplines=".5 0 .5 1" fill="freeze" />
```

Now, on every mouse move, your event listener needs to do three things:

- Set the `<animate from>` attribute to the current animated value of the `<fePointLight>` `element.x.animVal`/`element.y.animVal` property. This makes the animatin start from wherever the value currently is, even during a running animation.
- Set the `<animate to>` attribute to the `currentLightPos` value to move the animation towards its target.
- start the animation with the `<fePointLight>` `element.beginElement()` method, cancelling any currently running animation.

(If you were using a spline, you would have to set the `values` attribute instead of `from` and `to`.)

```
  const pointLight = $('fePointLight');
  const lightX = $('#anim_x');
  const lightY = $('#anim_y');

  lightX.attr({
    from: pointLight.prop('x').animVal,
    to: currentLightPos.x
  });
  lightX[0].beginElement();
  lightY.attr({
    from: pointLight.prop('y').animVal,
    to: currentLightPos.y
  });
  lightY[0].beginElement();
```

This lets the point light sort of "chase" the current mouse position, until the mouse move stops and the animation has a chance to run to its end.

```js
// lighting effect variables
let lightDist = 10000;
let currentLightPos = {
  x: -lightDist,
  y: -lightDist
};
let currentMousePos = {
  x: -1,
  y: -1
};
let windowWidth = $(window).outerWidth();
let windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
let ratio = {
  x: lightDist / (windowWidth / 2),
  y: lightDist / (windowHeight / 2)
};

const pointLight = $('fePointLight');
const lightX = $('#anim_x');
const lightY = $('#anim_y');

// when the window is resized
$(window).on('resize', function() {

  // update lighting effect variables
  windowWidth = $(window).outerWidth();
  windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
  ratio = {
    x: lightDist / (windowWidth / 2),
    y: lightDist / (windowHeight / 2)
  };

});

// when the mouse is moved (desktop)
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {

  // get our current mouse position
  currentMousePos.x = e.pageX;
  currentMousePos.y = e.pageY;

  // if mouse is on right side of window
  if (currentMousePos.x > (windowWidth / 2)) {

    // calculate the positive light x position
    currentLightPos.x = ratio.x * (currentMousePos.x - (windowWidth / 2));

    // if mouse is on left side of window
  } else if (currentMousePos.x < (windowWidth / 2)) {

    // calculate the negative light x position
    currentLightPos.x = -lightDist + (ratio.x * currentMousePos.x);

  }

  // calculate the negative light y position
  // if mouse is on bottom side of window
  if (currentMousePos.y > (windowHeight / 2)) {

    // calculate the positive light y position
    currentLightPos.y = ratio.y * (currentMousePos.y - (windowHeight / 2));

    // if mouse is on top side of window
  } else if (currentMousePos.y < (windowHeight / 2)) {

    // calculate the negative light y position
    currentLightPos.y = -lightDist + (ratio.y * currentMousePos.y);

  }
  
  // console.log(currentLightPos.x, currentLightPos.y);

  // update shine filter fePointLight attributes
  lightX.attr({
    from: pointLight.prop('x').animVal,
    to: currentLightPos.x
  });
  lightX[0].beginElement();
  lightY.attr({
    from: pointLight.prop('y').animVal,
    to: currentLightPos.y
  });
  lightY[0].beginElement();

});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<svg class="circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" filter="url(#shine)" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="shine" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="150%" height="150%">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4" result="blur" />
        <feSpecularLighting in="blur" surfaceScale="15" specularConstant="2.5" specularExponent="200" result="specOut" lighting-color="white">
          <fePointLight x="-10000" y="-10000" z="8000">
            <animate id="anim_x" attributeName="x"
                     begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" restart="always"
                     from="-10000" to="-10000" fill="freeze" />
            <animate id="anim_y" attributeName="y"
                     begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" restart="always"
                     from="-10000" to="-10000" fill="freeze" />
          </fePointLight>
        </feSpecularLighting>
        <feComposite in="specOut" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="specOut2" />
        <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut2" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" />
    </filter>
</svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I spent a couple of hours playing with this very cool stuff, thank you for deep explanation, you know your SVG! I managed to get keySplines one working too, I used a keySplines generator to try out different easing effects, and i'm probably guna stick with the linear thanks. This works great thanks!

Comment: I also parsed integers on currentLightPos so they were not floats, but the `animVal` I couldn't get to be integers, not sure why this is, maybe that is why the easing version wasn't super smooth as I needed.

Comment: I doubt that has anything to do with rounding - you have four significant digits before the fractional part, more than enough. But if the mouse changes position over a relevant distance between two `mousemove` events, this could change the speed of the animation in a way you may be able to spot. In addition, the computation of the filter might be more than your hardware is able to achieve between two events. Browsers then will slow down the speed of frame rendering. You could try to [throttle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181243) the number of mouse events

Comment: Thats not a bad idea, i will give that a go. Thanks