# Javascript debounce for mousemove event not working

Tags: javascript

I checked SO and found this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181243/throttling-a-mousemove-event-to-fire-no-more-than-5-times-a-second)
and wrote my solution [link](https://codepen.io/maximar1es/pen/GRQpBRN)
, but in reality it doesn't work.

**Task:**

1. Writing multiple blocks and adding a mouseover event listener to them.
2. After the event is fired, it will be processed with a debounce.
3. Displaying an event in the console

**My сode:**

```js
const cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card-wrapper');

function onMouseMoveHandler(e) {
  return debounce(() => update(e));
}

function debounce(func) {
  let isCan = true;
  
  return () => {
    if (isCan) {
      func();
      isCan = false;
      setTimeout(() => isCan = true, 500);
    }
   }
}

function update(e) {
  console.log(e);
}

for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  cards[i].onmousemove = onMouseMoveHandler;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.card-wrapper {
  margin: 2%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-wrapper card-1">
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>

<div class="card-wrapper card-2">
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you returning a function from your `debounce` function? `return () => {`

Comment: ... because `debounce` / `throttle` take a function as an argument and return a modified version (here a debounced respectively throttled behavior) of that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrapped `onMouseMoveHandler` in a function which prevents the debounced function from getting called. While you could do `debounce(...)()` to call it that won't be the behaviour you desire. Instead, you should make it a plain variable and assign it to the debounced function return from `debounce`.

```js
// no need for a function!
const onMouseMoveHandler = debounce((e) => update(e)); // or just debounce(update);

function debounce(func) {
  let isCan = true;
  
  return () => {
    if (isCan) {
      func();
      isCan = false;
      setTimeout(() => isCan = true, 500);
    }
   }
}

function update(e) {
  console.log(e);
}

for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  cards[i].onmousemove = onMouseMoveHandler;
}
```