# Get position relative to parent not viewport on mousedown / touchstart

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousedown, touchstart

How, on `mousedown` or `touchstart`, can I get the position of the mouse relative to or within the container or element it took place in.

So, I know I can get the `pageX/Y` or `clientX/Y` from the event or on touch, the original event. But that is the positioning compared to the whole viewport. This div is absolute positioned, so how can I get it positioned within the boundaries of its container ( absolute positioned ).

So this works: http://jsfiddle.net/Fb6An/

Here is the code:

```
$('.dataCard').on('mousedown touchstart', function(event){
    $(this).children('.ripple').show().css({'left':event.clientX || event.originalEvent.clientX, 'top':event.clientY || event.originalEvent.clientY});
});
```

Except it doesn't work in some elements on the full site that I am working on. On elements that are closer to the right edge of the screen, it appears more to the right and lower than the the actual mouse location. In elements to the left, it works fine.

**So I was wondering how can I get the position within an element and style the .ripple there?**

Comment: is the `.dataCard` the closest positioned element ? or is your html more complex with the closest positioned element unknown ?

Comment: see also [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2614472/283851) for the simplest solution I've seen so far. (plain DOM, no jQuery needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for jQuery when finding the coordinates to set as the `style`:

```
$('.dataCard').on('mousedown touchstart', function(event){
    var clickX = (event.clientX || event.originalEvent.clientX),
        clickY = (event.clientY || event.originalEvent.clientY);

    $(this).children('.ripple').each(function(){
        $(this)
            .show()
            .css({
                left: clickX - this.offsetParent.offsetLeft,
                top: clickY - this.offsetParent.offsetTop
            });
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle from @Gaby aka G. Petrioli: http://jsfiddle.net/s52u4/1/

In this particular case, using jQuery is like hitting a thumbtack with a sledge hammer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use position() on your container and calculate that in combination with event.screenX, event.screenY. That's what i would do in this case. Might as well wrap it into an extension

Comment: can you show me how to do that exactly? A quick demo or code? and edit the answer with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the [`.offsetParent()`](http://api.jquery.com/offsetparent) (*closest element that is positioned*) and subtract its [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset) values..

```
$('.dataCard').on('mousedown touchstart', function(event){
    var clickX = (event.clientX || event.originalEvent.clientX),
        clickY = (event.clientY || event.originalEvent.clientY);

    $(this).children('.ripple').each(function(){
        var ripple = $(this).show(),
            container = ripple.offsetParent(),
            offset = container.offset(),
            correctX = clickX - offset.left,
            correctY = clickY - offset.top;

        ripple.css({ left: correctX, top: correctY});
    });
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/s52u4/